# Portrait mode orientation problem with tabbarcontroller?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Using tabbarcontroller, shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method not calling for portrait mode while for other three orientation its calling perfectly. Did any have any idea about this ?

thanks

Comment: Not enough  info. You should post the code where this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even i faced the problem , If you just want to know whether the orientation of the device changed or not use notification instead of shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
-(void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)dict
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = (UIInterfaceOrientation)[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    //Your code
}
```

For Original problem, By default **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** return YES for *UIDeviceOrientationPortrait*, If you returned NO in **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** method, device will think that its in *UIDeviceOrientationPortrait* mode only hence the method **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** is not called for *UIDeviceOrientationPortrait*.

```
    (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
       //your code
        return NO;
 }
```

Comment: Are you returning NO in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method always.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with Device and Simulator?
Did you check supported orientation in your app_name-Info.plist?

Comment: I try in both. Same result. and in .plist i am not changing anything or restrict any thing ?

Comment: I'ts strange, are you sure you don't have "Supported interface orientation" key in the PList file?

Comment: damm sure .. nuthing related to orientation.